# How do I structure a cypher query to include paths between nodes from a MATCH clause without removing nodes that don't match the "full" pattern?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've tried this a number of ways so I won't list them all. Let me explain what I'm trying to achieve:

Let's say I have 3 types of nodes: A, B, and C, with possible directed links of form (:A)-->(:B) and (:B)-->(:C) and (:C)-->(:C).

What I want are the B and C nodes that come one and two links from a specific A node *and* any paths that exist that connect two C nodes together via a path that converges on a common C node.

First, I want to return the B and C nodes that come from a specific instance of A like:

```
MATCH (a:A)-->(b:B)-->(c:C)
RETURN b,c
```

What I also want to include are all the paths for which the set of nodes `c` converge on common `c` nodes. Something like

```
MATCH path=(c)-[*]->(c2:C)<-[*]-(c)
RETURN path
```

I've tried a bunch of ways and I usually either lose the (b) and (c) nodes that don't have such a path or else I get too too many (c2) nodes back that are not part of a path that connects a (c) node to another (c) node (such as if I use relationships of the form [*0..] in the query).

Comment: Please fix typo ("oen") in 3rd paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TheCrusher got me very close and I did a couple of modifications to get what I needed:

```
MATCH (a:A {name:"a_name"})-->(b:B)-->(c:C)
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT b) as bs, COLLECT(DISTINCT c) as cs
MATCH convergingPath=(c:C)-[*]->(c2:C)<-[*]-(c1:C)
WHERE c in cs AND c1 in cs AND c<>c1
RETURN bs, cs, convergingPath
```

Comment: Note that the `(c:C)-[*]->(c2:C)<-[*]-(c1:C)` pattern only requires that *at least one* interior node (between `c` and `c1`) have the `C` label. It does not require that all internal nodes have the `C` label. It is not clear if this satisfies your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, in my case it does implicitly satisfy them, I could also specify them based on a relationship label that is exclusive to that node-type. Is there another way?

Comment: If you have a relationship type (say, `FOO`) that is exclusively used between `C` nodes, then the following pattern should return only paths in which all interior nodes have the `C` label: `(c:C)-[:FOO*]->()<-[:FOO*]-(c1:C)`.

Comment: in this case, if you dont have converging C type nodes, it wont return any nodes .thats why i used Optional match there

Answer (score 1):

```
MATCH (a:A)-->(b:B)-->(c:C)
WITH a,COLLECT(DISTINCT b) as bNodes, COLLECT(DISTINCT c) as cNodes 
OPTIONAL MATCH (c:C)-->(c2:C)<--(c1:C)
WHERE c IN cNodes ANd c1 IN cNodes AND c<>c1 
WITH a ,bNodes,cNodes,c2 as convergePoint,COLLECT(DISTINCT c) AS convergingCNodes
RETURN a, bNodes,cNodes,convergePoint ,convergingCNodes
```

as far as i understood question, i guess this will return what you are looking for . "a" A node , all the connected B type nodes in bNodes,all the C type nodes in cNodes, if any c Type nodes are converging then converging point C type node is convergePoint and all the converging nodes on that convergePoint node in convergingCNodes

Comment: Thank you so much, it was very close to what I needed and with a few modifications I got it. Will post what I used as an answer.